# Http request from node server to Strapi throws error "econnrefused"

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I'm trying to access a strapi api in my local dev environement. Wheras I have no issues to access the api under the same url with postman, trying to access it from my node server i run into this error:

```
connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:1337
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 1337
```

This is the part of my server where I make the request:

```
const request = require('request');
        request({
      url: 'http://localhost:1337/api/homepage?populate=*',
      headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer 123455347'  },
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }, function(err, res) {
          if(err) {
            console.error(err);
          } else {
            console.log(res.body);
          }
    
    });
    }
```

Why refuses strapi the connection? I'm helpless.. Ist there something I missed while configuring it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue and I have found a work around inspired by a discussion on GitHub (https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3821).

The problem seems to be that Strapi does not support IPv6 properly with all Node-Versions (https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/12285).

When I try to access my Strapi-API with the address http://localhost:1337 my computer resolves the IPv6 address ::1: and this causes the beforehand mentioned error.

```
connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:1337
```

Therefore instead of trying to connect to http://localhost:1337 try to use the IPv4 address of your computer. In my case this meant to connect to http://192.168.0.12:1137.